# How can I add EventListener to textarea when entering/deleting the text of it (text-changing event)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, event-listener

I have a text-area without resize option (in html) and I want to addEventListener in javascript that will do something when the text of the textarea is changing.

```
<textarea id="searchFld" style="resize: none;">Text</textarea>

document.getElementById("searchFld").addEventListener('some text changing event', function);
```

pls rate normal, im a begginer here (: <3

Comment: Have you tried goolging before asking the question?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+event+change+textarea+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: `.addEventListener('input', function() {`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
const result = document.querySelector('#result')

textarea.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  result.textContent = e.target.value
})
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<p id='result'></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.getElementById("searchFld").addEventListener('change', e => console.log('change'));
document.getElementById("searchFld").addEventListener('input', e => console.log('input'));
```

```html
<textarea id="searchFld" style="resize: none;">Text</textarea>
```